# TypeError: 1st argument must be a real sequence 2 signal.spectrogram

Tags: pandas, numpy, scipy, signal-processing

I'm trying to take a signal from an electrical reading and decompose it into its spectrogram, but I keep getting a weird error. Here is the code:

```
f, t, Sxx = signal.spectrogram(i_data.values, 130)
plt.pcolormesh(t, f, Sxx)
plt.ylabel('Frequency [Hz]')
plt.xlabel('Time [sec]')
plt.show()
```

And here is the error:

```
convert_to_spectrogram(i_data.iloc[1000,:10020].dropna().values)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-140-e5951b2d2d97>", line 1, in <module>
    convert_to_spectrogram(i_data.iloc[1000,:10020].dropna().values)

  File "<ipython-input-137-5d63a96c8889>", line 2, in convert_to_spectrogram
    f, t, Sxx = signal.spectrogram(wf, 130)

  File "//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/signal/spectral.py", line 750, in spectrogram
    mode='psd')

  File "//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/signal/spectral.py", line 1836, in _spectral_helper
    result = _fft_helper(x, win, detrend_func, nperseg, noverlap, nfft, sides)

  File "//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/signal/spectral.py", line 1921, in _fft_helper
    result = func(result, n=nfft)

  File "//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mkl_fft/_numpy_fft.py", line 335, in rfft
    output = mkl_fft.rfft_numpy(x, n=n, axis=axis)

  File "mkl_fft/_pydfti.pyx", line 609, in mkl_fft._pydfti.rfft_numpy

  File "mkl_fft/_pydfti.pyx", line 502, in mkl_fft._pydfti._rc_fft1d_impl

TypeError: 1st argument must be a real sequence 2
```

My reading has a full cycle of 130 observations and its stored as individual values of a pandas df. The wave I am using in particular can be found [here](https://github.com/Travis-Barton/Personal-Projects/blob/master/wave.csv). Anyone have any ideas what this error means?

(Small disclaimer, I do not know much about signal processing, so please forgive me if this is a naive question)

Comment: How many columns in the `df`?  What `dtype`?

Comment: How are you obtaining i_data?

Comment: i_data is just a reading from an electrical line. The columns are a time series sequence of doubles.

Comment: So, is it a list, array,...?

Comment: I'm sorry. its a row of a pandas dataframe that I am using the .values method on, so it will be a numpy.ndarray

Comment: What is `dtype`?  Is it a `float` or `int`?

Comment: its a float, does it have to be an int?

Answer (score 2):

Python 3.6.9, scipy 1.3.3

Downloading your [file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Travis-Barton/Personal-Projects/master/wave.csv) and reading it with `pandas.read_csv`, I could generate the following spectrogram.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from scipy.signal import spectrogram
i_data = pd.read_csv('wave.csv')
f, t, Sxx = spectrogram(i_data.values[:, 1], 130)
plt.pcolormesh(t, f, Sxx)
plt.ylabel('Frequency [Hz]')
plt.xlabel('Time [sec]')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thats strange, what you have works for me too. But wave.csv was originally just a random row of a data frame of similar files. It doesn't seem to work when I take a row from the data frame. I suspect that I have a variable type problem.

Comment: If you print the shape of this row, what do you get?

Comment: (10019,) is what I get out

Comment: I can't explain it /: I'll try out a for loop? or something like that.